# Disable Local Account "User must change password at next logon"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create an local account that automatically signs in when Windows loads. However, when signing in for the first time, the account is prompted to set a password. However, this account does not have a password set because of the `-NoPassword` flag. This computer is not joined to any domains.

I tried setting the `-PasswordNeverExpires` flag, but upon checking in **lusrmgr.msc**, the `"User must set password on logon"` box is still checked.

`New-LocalUser "testmode" -NoPassword -FullName "test user" -Description "test sign-in account" -AccountNeverExpires`

`Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users" -Member "testmode"`

Automatically sign the account in without prompting to set a password

Comment: What does adding `-UserMayChangePassword $false` to your `New-LocalUser` do?  Does that still demand password change?  If you had AD (I know you don't), you would use `ChangePasswordAtLogon $false` to disable, but I am not sure if that works for `LocalUser` accounts similarly.

Comment: @gravity That flag doesn't work for New-LocalUser

"New-LocalUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UserMayChangePassword'.
At line:1 char:109
+ ... ption "User for the Kiosk Mode account" -UserMayChangePassword $False
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-LocalUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewLocalUserCommand"

Comment: Correction per [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) - it is a negative parameter not a positive one, my apologies: try instead using `-UserMayNotChangePassword $true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this please:
Here you are first creating the user, then piping to set the properties of said user.

```
New-LocalUser -Name "testmode" -NoPassword -AccountNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword -FullName "test user" -Description "test sign-in account" | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

It should yield this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. What part of the command is actually disabling "User must change password at next logon"?

Comment: | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true , in conjunction with: -NoPassword , first we are creating the account w/ basic properties, then we are editing the account via pipe:  | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true .